# What is the purpose of a Data Transfer Object in NestJS?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, dto, data-transfer-objects

Im struggling with a problem. Im following the documentation of NestJS. The back-end framework for NodeJS. The documentation mentions a DTO (Data Transfer Object). I created a DTO for creating a user:

```
export class CreateUserDto {
    readonly email: string;
    readonly password: string;
}
```

In combination with this:

```
@Post('create')
createUser(@Body() userData: CreateUserDto): User {
    return this.usersService.createUser(userData);
}
```

For some reason, I am able to make a post request to this route with any type of body. I can place any type of information in the body without getting an error. The whole point of such a DTO is to allow only certain information in the body, right? Instead of using export class CreateUserDTO i also tried export interface CreateUserDTO, but this isn't working either. I am new to typescript and NestJS as well. Is there anyone who might be able to explain why it's not working the way I expected or what the purpose is of such a Data Transfer Object?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The DTO on it's own is more of a guideline for the developer and those who consume the API to know what kind of shape the request body expects to be, it doesn't actually run any validations **on its own**. However, with Typescript you can add in decorators from the [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) library and and use the [built-in ValidationPipe](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation) and have validations run on your incoming requests so that only the expected request body can come in.

In short, the DTO is the definition of what the request *should* look like, but because JavaScript is a dynamic language, you can send in anything. That's why libraries like `class-validator` and `runtypes` exist.

Comment: thanks @Jay McDoniel. I am using your nest repository on my private lessons, quite nice! thanks twice!

Answer (score 6):

At runtime all types are lost, so the controller accepts whatever JSON comes from request body. If you want a type check, you should enable a ValidationPipe that leverages [class-trasformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) and [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) libraries:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      transform: true,
      transformOptions: {
        enableImplicitConversion: true,
      },
      validationError: { target: false, value: false },
    })
  );
```